# Delete a folder with no owner in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, permissions, powershell

I'm using Windows 8.1 and I'm trying to delete a folder on a secondary hard drive.  I tried a things that I had read here, but nothing seems to be working.

Here's what I've done:

1. Tried `rd` command in Windows Powershell to remove the folder.  It said access denied.
2. Right click the folder, clicked Properties, Security, Advanced and I see that there is no owner of the folder.  This is odd.
3. The folder is set to read-only and I cannot change it to archive because i get access denied.
4. I tried making a delete.bat file with the following in it:

   ```
   SET DIRECTORY_NAME="D:\xampp\htdocs\webfolder\!ARCHIVE\httpdocs\sites\default\files"
   TAKEOWN /f %DIRECTORY_NAME% /r /d y
   ICACLS %DIRECTORY_NAME% /grant administrators:F /t
   PAUSE
   ```

I run this as Admin and it does not work, i get a access denied error. Weird.

5. The last thing i tried was in Windows Powershell ran as Admin, I used this command:

   ```
   icacls files /reset /T
   ```
6. I just tried this too and i get access denied, so i cant takeown of it.

   ```
   takeown /f <directory> /r
   ```

   I get Access Denied.

Can someone help?  I'd really like to remove these folder from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved!**

Originally, i had performed a Cut + Paste operation to move all of the files and folders from the D drive to my C drive. I had gotten a few errors for a few files that said that i can't move these files because the length of filenames was too long.

I was going through each folder that remained and deleting them after getting the files out of those folders.  Then I ran into a problem where it would let me delete the "files" folder.  I tried a bunch of different things with no luck.

Out of desperation, I decided to restart my computer. TADA!  That solved the problem.  When i go that folders location, the folder is now gone.  Perhaps it was a ghost in the machine.

Moral of the story is always try a reboot before posting to the forums! :)